# Changing display attribute by dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

So I'm trying to make an interactive form where the value of one dropdown affects the content of another drop down. I have seen some similar question on SO, and I decided to take the best from all answers. Anyway I'm stuck at the last part and can't seem to figure out why it wont work.

The form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Dienst</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <select id="dienst" name="dienst" class="form-control">
        <option value"" disable selected>&nbsp;</option>
        <option value="Psychiatrie">Psychiatrie</option>
        <option value="Oncologie">Oncologie</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Ziekte</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <select name="ziekte" class="form-control">
        <option value"" disable selected>&nbsp;</option>
        <option class="Psychiatrie_select" value"" >Jong Dementie</option>
        <option class="Psychiatrie_select" value"" >Neuropsychiatrische stoornissen</option>
        <option class="Oncologie_select" value"" >Other</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The JS code

```
$('select#dienst').on('change', function() {
event.preventDefault();
var dienst = $('[name="dienst"]').val();

if(dienst == "Psychiatrie"){
  document.getElementsByClassName(Psychiatrie_select).style.display = 'block';
}
});
```

The logic behind it:

I first get the value of the first drop down list ( id = dienst ) and based on that I want to change the display value of the options of the second drop down ( where class is Psychiatrie_select )

I have also debugged by console.log(dienst) and that shows that the selection of the first drop down menu is stored in dienst. What could be wrong because my css display attribute doesn't seem to change.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. Thus you have it like `document.getElementsByClassName("Psychiatrie_select")[0].style.display = 'block';`

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you! I didn't know about the array!

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection of elements, of elements, which you need to iterate over: so if you required second one than so that the 0 index one because there is not any other element whose name is "Psychiatrie_select" so document.getElementsByClassName("Psychiatrie_select")[0].style.display = 'block'; it will work.